# Kann ich sagen "Ferien sind"?

Tags: grammar-identification

In meiner anderen Frage haben wohl die Leser den Sinn der Frage nicht verstanden, deshalb noch einmal in einer separaten Frage.

Ich habe "Es sind Ferien.", die Aussage, dass Ferien sind. Ich gehe davon aus, dass das "es" ein Platzhalter-es sein muss. Demnach will ich sagen können "Ferien sind.". Ist das möglich oder ist es das nicht? Wieso? Wenn nein, was ist das "es" denn dann? Siehe meine andere Frage. Ist der Grund zur Frage ein Missverständnis über das Platzhalter-es? Klärt mich bitte auf.

Comment: You could simply edit and try to clarify your question... there is no answer yet

Comment: Ich fand deine andere Frage klar genug.